# JSP, Java and Database. How to invoke the same index.jsp one more time if incorrect data were submitted while trying to login?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, jakarta-ee

I can connect to database but I am not able to reinvoke the same index.jsp file if incorrect data are passed while trying to login.

After I connect to database the index.jsp file is displayed and I put email and password with this data: a.smith@gmail.com 1234. These data are in my database so it redirect me to the menu.jsp page but also if I put incorrect data: a.sm@gmail.com 12 it also redirects me to menu.jsp.Now I get this error:

```
Mar 30, 2014 12:14:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Cap] threw exception [/index.jsp     
(line: 33, column: 41) quote symbol expected] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 33, column: 41) quote symbol expected
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    ..........
```

Line 33 in index.jsp is

```
 <jsp:getProperty name="login" property="value" />
```

getEmail and getPasword not return null only good value as expected.

```
    <jsp:useBean id="member" class="StaffMember" scope="session"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="member" property="*"/>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <font size=4>

    <center>
    </center>
    <form method=post> <hr><br>
    <center>
    <b>LOGIN</b><p>
    <input type=text name=email value= email value = member.setEmail(email)> <p>
    <input type=text name=password value=password value = member.setPassword(password)> <p>
    <input type=submit value="Submit">
    <jsp:getProperty name="login" property="value" />
 <c:if value = "false" action="index.jsp"></c:if>
 <c:if value = "true" action="menu.jsp"></c:if>
    </center>
    <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/ndnuLogo.jpg"/>
    <br><hr>
    </form>
    </font>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable;

    public class LoginServiceImplem implements LoginService{
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;
    private boolean value; //used to check if user that login is on the list of user available to 
                          //test

    public LoginServiceImplem() throws SQLException{
            connection = null;
            statement = null;
        value = false;
        StaffMember sm = new StaffMember();
        value = login(sm.getEmail(), sm.getPassword());
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
    return value;
    }

public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

public boolean login(String email, String password) throws SQLException{
        System.out.println(email + " " + password);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM cap.member WHERE Email= '" + email + "'"
                + " AND Password = '" + password + "'";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
            //builds a connection and statement
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + 
            "cap", "root", "");
            System.out.println("After connection");
            statement = connection.createStatement(); 
            System.out.println("After statement");
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("After rs");
            //if the statement returns something
            if(rs.next()){
                //and email and password match the database information, return true
                return(email.equals(rs.getString("Email")) 
                        && password.equals(rs.getString("Password")));
            }
        }finally {
            //close all connections
            DbUtil.close(rs);
            DbUtil.close(statement);
            DbUtil.close(connection);
        }return false;
    }
}
```

```
public class StaffMember {

    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;

    public StaffMember() {  
        emailAddress = "a.smith@gmail.com";
        password = "1234";  
    }

    /* The setEmail method sets the employee's email */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
    emailAddress = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pword){
        password = pword;
    }

    /* The getEmail method gets the employee's email. */
    public String getEmail() {
        return emailAddress;
    }    

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a NPE in your code, but you did not show those parts. Please show the login method and tell us more about line 78 (and start using a debugger!): `java.lang.NullPointerException
at ndnu.ws.LoginServiceImplem.login(LoginServiceImplem.java:78)`

Comment: you have created `StaffMember sm = new StaffMember();` and passing `sm.getEmail()` and `sm.getPassword()`. these values might be null and your login method is throwing NPE.

Comment: home and sakura. I did update my post.

Comment: its the connection object which is null... check with credentials if are they correct. if it is correct, check with the DB provider the way to connect and you are using the latest jar files

Comment: Yes Punith Raj. I am in the process of testing connection to database.

Comment: I just made updated to my post to make sure everything is up to date. I still cannot connect to db. Now I think is more technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have not missed anything I think the error "No suitable driver found" comes because of not having the below line in Java code. Let me know if I am missing anything.

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

you can add this in "LoginServiceImplem" class. in a static block something like

```
static {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
```

Comment: A Paul. I added this part of the code and was able to connect to database. The index.jsp file is displayed and I put email and password with this data: a.smith@gmail.com 1234. This data are in my database so it redirect me to the menu.jsp page but also if I put incorrect data: a.sm@gmail.com 12 it redirects me to menu.jsp. I want say that part of index.jsp file is incorect than: <jsp:getProperty name="login" property="value"/>
    <c:if value = "false" action="index.jsp"></c:if>

Comment: did not understood you question. please describe.

Comment: Why can I go to the next page, menu.jsp, if I provide incorrect data while trying to login? I should not be able to do that if I provide incorrect email or password. login method returns true if the person was able to login. This part of the code: if(rs.next()){
return(email.equals(rs.getString("Email")) && password.equals(rs.getString("Password"))); }  returns true if the data entered much the data that are in the table member otherwise it return false. If it return false it should invoke one more time index.jsp and person need to try login one more time.

Comment: if you know JSP I would really appreciate your help

Comment: I think in your action you have written action="menu.jsp". So any time you submit the form it will go to menu.jsp. I think it is better to keep a servlet in the middle. The submit from jsp should send the request to the servlet, the servlet will forward to the proper jsp depending upon the result from the LoginServiceImplem call.

Comment: A Paul. I removed action="menu.jsp" from the form tag. I put this lines   <jsp:getProperty name="login" property="value" />
 <c:if value = "false" action="index.jsp"></c:if>
 <c:if value = "true" action="menu.jsp"></c:if> in the body. I still get error that I edited in my post.

Comment: It will not work like this buddy, if you dont put the "action in the form" then it will be submitted to itself. So try the solution from my previous comment, introduce a servlet.